# Не могу вывести данные из БД в активити

Tags: java, android, база-данных, android-studio

Всем доброго вечера!
В общем проблема такая: создал БД в DB Browser for SQLite, подключил её, и хочу вывести из неё данные на активити по нажатию кнопки. У меня в БД есть таблица с упражнениями, хочу вывести на активити название упражнения и описание этого упражнения, но ничего не получается. К тому же появляются 2 ошибки, которые я не знаю как исправить.
Вот код activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
     <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:onClick=""
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.08"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="58dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="505dp"
    android:layout_height="596dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.305" />
```

Вот код DataBaseHelper.java:

```
 package com.example.valery.workwithdb;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.SQLException; 
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.OutputStream;


 public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// путь к базе данных вашего приложения
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.valery.workwithdb/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "database";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context mContext;


/**
 * Конструктор
 * Принимает и сохраняет ссылку на переданный контекст для доступа к ресурсам приложения
 *
 * @param context
 */
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.mContext = context;

}

/**
 * Создает пустую базу данных и перезаписывает ее нашей собственной базой
 */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        //ничего не делать - база уже есть
    } else {
        //вызывая этот метод создаем пустую базу, позже она будет перезаписана
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Проверяет, существует ли уже эта база, чтобы не копировать каждый раз при запуске приложения
 *
 * @return true если существует, false если не существует
 */

private boolean checkDataBase() {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        //база еще не существует
    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Копирует базу из папки assets заместо созданной локальной БД
 * Выполняется путем копирования потока байтов.
 */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    //Открываем локальную БД как входящий поток
    InputStream myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    //Путь ко вновь созданной БД
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Открываем пустую базу данных как исходящий поток
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //перемещаем байты из входящего файла в исходящий
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //закрываем потоки
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}


public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    //открываем БД
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}



@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
```

}

MainActivity.java:

```
 package com.example.valery.workwithdb;

 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.SQLException;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button; 
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import java.io.IOException;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    // myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    try {
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    }

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(/*cytaty*/MainActivity.this);
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();

            String text = myDbHelper.getYourData(); //this is the method to query

            myDbHelper.close();
            // set text to your TextView
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText(text);
        }
    });

}

public String[] getData() {
    public String[] getAppCategoryDetail() {

        final String TABLE_NAME = "exercises";

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  _name, _text WHERE _id = 1 FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        String[] data = null;

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                // get the data into array, or class variable
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return data;
      }


  }
 }
```

Ошибки:
E:\AndroidProjects\WorkwithDB\app\src\main\java\com\example\valery\workwithdb\MainActivity.java

Error:(55, 9) error: illegal start of expression

Error:(55, 45) error: ';' expected

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: у вас там что, метод getAppCategoryDetail() определяется внутри метода getData()? - это неприемлемо в Java/ Вообще рекомендую вам внимательнее набирать код и проверять его, пытаться самому разобраться в подобных синтаксических ошибках, лучше проникнуться синтаксисом и правилами языка Java, а не сразу писать куда то.

Comment: и никакого метода getYourData() , я в классе DataBaseHelper не вижу. Из того кода, что вы написали, я бы вам порекомендовал лучше освоить теорию, почитать побольше о работе с БД в Android, потом уже писать код. То, что есть сейчас как бы несколько ужасно и хорошо видно, что вы не вполне понимаете, что и зачем делается в вашем коде.

Comment: Судя по тому, что вы пишите сейчас, задавать вопросы на подобных ресурсах вам не сильно поможет, так как у вас отсутствует элементарная база знаний. Найдите книгу Б.Харди "Android. Программирование для профессионалов" 2-е издание и прочитайте ее, лучше всю, но там есть и большой раздел по работе с SQLite на примере реального приложения с подробными пояснениями.  Так же, судя по вашим ошибкам и не способности их исправить, сначала вам нужно почитать что то о Core Java , книги Эккеля или Шилдта. А задавая тут вопросы с такими элементарными проблемами вы и за 5 лет свое приложение не напишите.